# Find a basis and the dimension of the solution space W of the following homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Good morning, I need help with this problem.

Find a basis and the dimension of the solution space $W $of the following homogeneous system

$\begin{cases}
x+2y-2z+2s-t=0\\
x+2y-z+3s-2t=0\\
2x+4y-7z+s+t=0
\end{cases}
 $

Comment: What are your thoughts, what have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi @GregMartin I Try make a linear combination and solve the system by Gauss-Jordan, but really I do not understand very well what I have to find

Comment: Perhaps you can include that information in the question then, and ask specifically for help understanding the actual statement of the question.

Comment: You can also have a look at some older posts asking about similar problem. For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603228/find-basis-of-solutions-of-this-linear-system, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702951/easiest-way-to-solve-system-of-linear-equations-involving-singular-matrix or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382907/finding-the-kernel-of-a-linear-map (You can also try some of the questions listed among related questions in the sidebar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $W$ is the [null space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NullSpace.html) of the matrix
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & -1 & 3 & -2 \\
2 & 4 & -7 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Recall that $A$ and the [reduced row-echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) of $A$ have the same null space. We can compute $\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A$ using [row-reductions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Row_Reduction_and_Echelon_Forms). In our case we have
$$
\rref{A}=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
Here, $\rref A$ has two pivot columns, so the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) tells us that $W$ has dimension
$$
\dim W=(\#\text{ columns of }A)-(\#\text{ pivot columns of }\rref A)=5-2=3
$$
Can you find three linearly independent vectors in the null space of $\rref A$?

Comment: Brian, thanks for the theorem, i don't know about the theorem. Thank man, i go to make the other exercise!